# Can a crabapple scion graft to an apple rootstock?

Tags: apples, grafting, crabapples

Given that apple trees can be pollinated from crabapples are apple rootstocks compatible with crabapple scions also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as crabapples and production apples are the same genus and species (*Malus domestica*). Typically, though, it's edible apples that are grafted onto crabapples. This is often done "high" so that an existing crabapple can become a many-variety production apple tree.